# Does websockets data need to be sanitize?

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am new to node.js and websockets. I was thinking back on SQL and wondered if my WebSockets need to be sanitized, can code be injected somehow? I searched around for an answer and learned a lot about best practices with authentications but nothing about sanitizing the data leading to think it's not really a problem unless I am passing that data to a SQL query or something.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what kind of data is being transferred. From what I know about websockets, it's usually used for transferring data to clients from servers and clients don't have to reload the page again and again. One example I can think of is Jenkins Console Output.

Comment: Jenkins is usually housed behind a VPN and with only "trusted users" having access;I doubt anyone would try to hack it.  I wanted my WebSocket to be publicly accessible by "Non-trusted users", I have to assume people will actively try to hack it.